# proper date format for time series precipitation analysis

Tags: r, datetime, posix

I have 100 yrs precipitation and temperature data that I would like to analyze using the 'seas' package. I have tried several formats for the date column and get the following error code every time:

> Error in seas.df.check(x, orig, var) : 
>   a ‘date’ column must exist in ‘srs_precip’

Example code below, where I have tried to coerce Gregorian dates into `Date`, also `Date.POSIX` but still get error message from 'seas' library.

```
   Year     yr.m.d       Date date.J Inches mm_SRS Max_Temp_F Max_Temp_C Min_Temp_F   Min_Temp_C Date.POSIX
1  1919 1919-01-01 1919-01-01      1      0      0         39   3.888889         26 -3.333333333 1919-01-01
2  1919 1919-01-02 1919-01-02      2      0      0         35   1.666667         19 -7.222222222 1919-01-02
3  1919 1919-01-03 1919-01-03      3      0      0         40   4.444444         14          -10 1919-01-03
4  1919 1919-01-04 1919-01-04      4      0      0         52  11.111111         20 -6.666666667 1919-01-04
5  1919 1919-01-05 1919-01-05      5      0      0         43   6.111111         20 -6.666666667 1919-01-05
6  1919 1919-01-06 1919-01-06      6      0      0         56  13.333333         31 -0.555555556 1919-01-06
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `names(df)[3] <- "date"`? It may be that it is looking for a column called "date" (case-sensitive)?

Comment: I've tried naming the date column using capitalization and lower case, get the same error message either way.